# Havdalah - how important is it?

Tags: shabbat, havdalah

Is Shabbat over when the sun has gone down or is Shabbat over after the Havdalah ceremony?

If it is the latter, does the Shabbat keep going for the rest of the week? Since the Torah says that Shabbat is on the last day of the week, could one have Shabbat on the wrong day? Would it still be Shabbat?

Is Havdalah a good thing or something you need to in order to end Shabbat?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Eagel. I allowed myself to edit your question for clarity and hope to have preserved what you wanted to ask. See below for a first answer and some sources. Hope you will stick around, ask more questions and learn with us

Comment: There are five separate questions enumerated in this post. Please break them apart into separate questions so that proper attention can be given to each detail.

Answer (score 2):

**Shabbat ends once there are three mid-sized stars in the sky.** After that time, it is enough to say "*barukh hamavdil ben kodesh lehol*" (blessed is the One who separates between holy and mundane) to be able to do work. Those praying the evening shmonei esrei say the extra passage of *ata chonantanu* which is enough to enable them to do work.

Havdala is nevertheless an obligation but can be performed until Tuesday night.

In any case, whether one performs Havdala or not, says *hamavdil* or not, Shabbat returns next Friday night.

See [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch siman 96](http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.96?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) for further sources and details or [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/howto/wizard_cdo/aid/256963/jewish/1-What-is-Havdalah.htm) and [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/95904/jewish/Havdalah-and-the-Conclusion-of-Shabbat.htm).

Comment: I am not clear on what your answer is. Baruckh hamavdil *is* havdallah, albeit a shortened version.

Comment: @LN6595 the OP's first question was what ends Shabbat? Havdala or the night. I answered it was the night. I then clarified the role of Havdala to start doing work. Hamavdil is enough to work, but the obligation of Havdala (on wine, spices and light) remains.

Comment: mbloch: But i still don´t understand.If the night ends  the shabbat,but the holyness of shabbat is still in the "air"?So you need that to end as well or separate it from the rest of the week?

Comment: @Eagel Shabbat ends indeed with the nightfall. It is not holiness in the air which needs to end. It is Man which needs to acknowledge the difference between the holiness of Shabbat and the mundane of the week. Once we acknowledge this we can start work.